# How to hide a div with specific text using only css?

Tags: css, class

```
<div class="classname"> text1 </div>
<div class="classname"> text2 </div>
```

i want to hide only div having text "text2" without changing html - only using css

Comment: If we can add extra classname to div using css only - that also will work.. but how? dont know :(

Comment: You can use this CSS: `div:nth-child(2){ display: none;}` - https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/8hox5rnd/

Comment: @LuísP.A. your suggestion worked (Y) Thank you so much :)